# Arrangements of 12 people into groups

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to arrange 12 people into groups of 2, 4, and 6? I came up with the answer 12C2 * 10C4 * 6C6. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct. You can of course omit the last factor, since it’s $1$; besides, once you’ve chosen the pair and the quartet, the remaining six people **must** form the third group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s correct. You can of course omit the last factor, since it’s $1$; besides, once you’ve chosen the pair and the quartet, the remaining six people **must** form the third group, so you know that it’s $1$ even without computing the binomial coefficient.